In QGIS points sized by an attribute does not show any graphics in the layout legend
When I in QGIS size points by an attribute using the Assistant in Symbology, the legend in the layout does not shown any dots unless I manually go into the legend in the layout and for every dot replaces it with a custom symbol where I remove the scaling.
Is there an easier way to do this?


It's not the perfect solution, but if you aren't aiming to display the difference in size in the legend, you can create a duplicate layer with the colour categories only and use that in the legend instead. Its visibility can be checked off in the main canvas, but it will still be recognised by the legend item.

Try setting a value for 'Size when NULL' in the Assistant. That has worked for me.

Yes it is set to a small value

But is it set to a value corresponding the size, you want the symbol shown with in the legend?

Ah I didn’t get that - and yes it actually works. But it must also mean that on your map null values will be shown in that size then I suppose

Oh yes, you are right!! However it seems, that you can circumvent this by editing the size expression, that is imposed by the Assistant, and change the default value in case of NULL values back to 0.
I made a test, where the Assistant created the following expression:
coalesce(scale_polynomial("pointsize", 0, 100, 2, 8, 0.57), 2)
I simple changed this to:
coalesce(scale_polynomial("pointsize", 0, 100, 2, 8, 0.57), 0)
and now my point with a NULL value is not shown, but the legend is okay!

OK, that is a workaround yes.
But I think it can not be intentional that QGIS acts like that?
Perhaps one should file an issue?
